# Discord music bot stopped working for some reason

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Basically, I asked on here before about this bot I was making and when I started to code the music command's it just stopped working it will still turn on in the VSCode terminal but when I type the command it says the there is a Reference error saying PREFIX undefined any help would be great here is the code.

````
const client = new Discord.Client();

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

const prefix = '$';

var servers = {};

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is on!');
});


//Music Command



client.on(`message`, message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));


                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });


            }

            if($args[1]){
                message.channel.send("provide a link!");
                return;
            }

            if($message.member.voice.channel){
                message.channel.send("you must be in a channel for me to join and play the music!");
                return;
            }

            if($servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if ($message.member.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(conncection, message);

            })

            
        }    
});```
````

Comment: What's "PREFIX" supposed to be? I see a "prefix" but no "PREFIX".

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. `prefix` is not the same as `PREFIX`

Comment: here is the terminal error: ReferenceError: PREFIX is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thott\Desktop\Bot 2\main.js:22:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\thott\Desktop\Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\thott\Desktop\Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)

Comment: You were just answered twice about what the issue is, take the time to actually read responses

Comment: It's literally telling you exactly what the error is, and where it's located. If something about the error or your expectations of the language doesn't jibe, double-check your assumptions (like regarding case sensitivity in variable names) by searching the web, or JS documentation, like on MDN) and see if that resolves it.